# Orbeon form how to redirect to a mobile app link after successful submission?

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to set up a submission button to redirect to my mobile app on successful submission. The mobile app URI looks something like my-app://

I tested the URI on an IOS simulator in Safari and it opens the app correctly, but when I submit an Orbeon form I'm redirected to the default Orbeon admin view (the one that shows all the form instances). So I assume the redirect failed or the URI wasn't able to be read by Orbeon.

Here's what the property looks like:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.close.*.*"> 
     relinquish-lease                                                         
     then navigate(uri = "{xxf:evaluate(xxf:property('props.services-url'))}")
     recover summary
</property>
```

Where **props.services-url** is set like so:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="props.services-url">
     if (xxf:get-request-parameter('Portal') = 'Web') then 'https://some-website.com'
     else if (xxf:get-request-parameter('Portal') = 'Mobile') then 'my-app://'
     else ''
</property>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try replacing the entire code of your process by just `navigate(uri = "my-app://")`? If so, does the navigation happen in that case? -Alex

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you described as "default Orbeon admin view (the one that shows all the form instances)" is what in Orbeon Forms is called the [summary page](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/features/summary-page).

> ```xml
> <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.close.*.*">
>     relinquish-lease
>     then navigate(uri = "{xxf:evaluate(xxf:property('props.services-url'))}")
>     recover summary
> </property>
> ```

Based on the code of your `close` process quoted above, the summary page is loaded if `relinquish-lease` fails. Is it possible that this is what happens in your case? What if you change the code for this process to just do the following, also hardcoding the URL for simplicity:

```xml
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.close.*.*">
    navigate(uri = "my-app://")
</property>
```